# Laravel Vapor CategoryHttpLibrary bot control rule

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-waf, laravel-vapor

When using the Laravel Vapor provided bot control rule CategoryHttpLibrary, API requests made by my own application are blocked as well. How can I whitelist these API requests while still blocking malicious traffic?